# Tangent line with trigonometry and implicit differentiation

Tags: trigonometry, implicit-differentiation, tangent-line

Can anyone help confirm me if the following expression correct or wrong?
[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjNwm.png)

y is the equation of tangent line.

Comment: Welcome to mse. You should latex up your questions directly on site rather than linking to external pictures.  See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for a tutorial on how to do this.

Comment: I agree with @DanielBuck !

Comment: Your answer is not what I get. Though you seem to be okay in every part of the calculation up to it, you appear to have messed up the evaluation. Word of advise: As soon as you finish taking the derivative of both sides, immediately plug in the values $x = \pi/4, y = 0$, then simplify for $y'$. You will find (particularly when $y = 0$) that much of the difficulty in your calculation was not needed.

Comment: Ah thanks for the trick. My calculation was not right at the last statement. Saw it.

Answer (score 0):

I miscalculated the last part. The answer is $$y'= \frac{2}{\pi ^2+4}$$